# Eliminate NULL records in distinct select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL SERVER 2008

```
Relation : Employee

empid   clock-in  clock-out  date      Cmpid
1        10        11      17-06-2015   001
1        11        12      17-06-2015   NULL 
1        12         1      NULL         001 
2        10        11      NULL         002
2        11        12      NULL         002
```

I need to populate table temp :

```
insert into temp
select distinct empid,date from employee
```

This gives all
3 records since they are distinct but what 
I need is

```
empid  date          CMPID
1      17-06-2015     001
2      NULL           002
```

Comment: the 2 first are not distinct. for the last one `where date not null` should do

Comment: But you haven't included `Cmpid` in your query, so how can the result a) return 3 distinct rows, and b) have column `CMPID`? Can you describe in words exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size and scope of your table, it might just be more prudent to add

`WHERE columnName is not null AND columnName2 is not null` to the end of your query.

Comment: In case the date field for all records of empid 2 is NULL then I need a record: 2  NULL in my output

Comment: Oh, I see... So the data you need for each entry may be spread across 3 or more records and you're trying to find a way to return it without querying everything and getting a bunch of nulls. I may have a fix but it'll take time. In the meantime i'd suggest editing your initial question; it was a tad confusing for me.

Comment: Oops sorry!!.. I have just edited the dataset a bit which is exactly required

Answer (score 0):

Null is different from other date value. If you wont exclude null record you have to add a and condition like table.filed is not null.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is a result table containing a *row* or *tuple* (relational databases don't have records) for every employee with a `date` column showing the date on which the worked or `null` if they didn't work. Right?

Something like this should do you:

```
select e.employee_id
from      ( select distinct
                   empid
            from employee
          ) master
left join employee detail on detail.empid = master.empid
                         and detail.date is not null
```

The `master` virtual table gives you the set of destinct employees; the `detail` gives you employees with non-null dates on which they worked. The `left join` gives you everything from `master` with any matches from `detail` blended in.

Rows in `master` with no matching rows in `details`, are returned once with the contributing columns from `detail` set to `null`. Rows in `master` with matching rows in `detail`are repeated once for each such match, with the `detail` columns reflecting the matching row's values.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the lowest date or null for each empid

```
SELECT  empid, 
        MIN(date) date, 
        MIN(cmpid) cmpid
FROM    employee
GROUP BY empid
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
      select distinct empid,date from employee where date is not null
```

Comment: In case the date field for all records of empid 2 is NULL then I need a record: 2 NULL in my output.